# SSL certificate problem while installing mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am getting the following error while installing mongoDB on macOS by following command:

```
brew install mongodb-community@6.0
```

Error:

```
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
More details here: https://curl.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.
```

I tried searching on it internet but nothing worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with curl not with Homebrew, add the -k flag.

Try this:

```
curl -fsSLk https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install
```

Comment: I ran the command , but I am getting below output on the terminal.
`curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404`